# Add osgi bundle to Virgo Runtime server

Tags: eclipse, osgi, eclipse-neon, eclipse-virgo

I'm trying to test Eclipse Virgo server as OSGi container for my bundles. I was wishing to get easy debug possibilities, compared to deploying all bundles through Karaf console and remote debugging.

I've followed the instructions from https://wiki.eclipse.org/Virgo/Tooling and installed Tooling form site http://download.eclipse.org/virgo/snapshot/tooling (the link to update site from https://www.eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/virgo-documentation-3.6.4.RELEASE/docs/virgo-tooling-guide/html/ch03.html shows no updates). The installation was a bit crude, I've got not-so-nice screen:
[image] 
and afterwards Eclipse didn't start, I was forced to start it from command line with -clean param.

However, afterwards, I was able to add Virgo Runtime server, but when I click Add Resources, I got a message: There are no resources that can be added or removed from the server.

The OSGi bundles are added to the workspace and are OSGised with maven-bundle-plugin. They are correct OSGi bundles, however, Virgo doesn't seem to recognize them.

Has the installation failed? Is Virgo incompatibile with Eclipse Neon? Or just something else went wrong?

Comment: What actually went wrong? It looks like the installation of Virgo Tools succeeded. After the screenshot your description gets very vague. It sounds almost like you're trying to turn your IDE into a Virgo server.

Comment: @NeilBartlett I don't know, only Tools get installed, and afterwards workspace crashed. After another restart I was able to create Virgo Runtime, but I'm unable to add any project to it...

Comment: Sorry, again this is quite vague. In what sense are you unable to do this? It could be that you just don't know how. Or did you try something and nothing happens? Or was there an error message (if so, what did it say)?

Comment: @NeilBartlett I've simply clicked Add/Remove, like by f.g. Tomcat, but nothing was on the list, although I've got in workspace WAR projects and bundle projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Projects must have a specific nature to be deployable on Virgo. In Eclipse, a nature is a facet of a project that gives it specific features or behaviour.

If you are using bnd tools to create the projects, it should be possible to add them to the Virgo Runtime after right clicking over the project, selecting the Virgo menu and choosing "Add OSGi Bundle Project nature". After doing that you may also have to access project properties and associate the project to the Virgo runtime.

[image]

If you are using PDE to create the projects, you should use the dedicated Virgo PDE wizard (New -> Virgo -> PDE Bundle Project) instead of the PDE default one. If your projects have been created earlier with PDE, I suggest you create a new Virgo PDE Bundle Project and compare .project files to figure out how to change the .project file of your existig PDE projects to make them usable with Virgo.

The Virgo Tools also provide another wizard for creating OSGi bundle projects which are not PDE plug-in projects. Please have a look at the tooling documentation for understanding the differences http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/virgo-documentation-3.7.0.M01/docs/virgo-tooling-guide/html/index.html

Note, I am an Eclipse Virgo committer.

Comment: Is it possible to add maven-built bundles as well?

Comment: It should be possible as long as: 
1 - the projects are given the proper nature and associated to the runtime as explained above and
2 - when compiled in Eclipse, all the content of the project (including META-INF/MANIFEST.MF) is copied into the /bin folder of the project, because the Eclipse integration will deploy your workspace project by copying the content of the /bin folder of your project into the VIRGO-HOME/stage folder.

Comment: So the nature must be added manually, or is it possible to do that via maven-eclipse-plugin? For sake of team interoperatibility, I'd like to minimize the amount of things that must be locally configured.

Comment: At present I believe it must be done manually. There is no Virgo-specific m2e connector that would do this implicitly for you, especially since the project <packaging> in your pom.xml is most likely "jar" and that type is already taken by the Eclipse maven connector plug-in that manages standard Java projects (non OSGi).